# How to get the last line as Index in a text file with python like len[arry]-1) on a arry?

Tags: python, algorithm, search, text-files

I have a very large file of hashes and a hash I gave. I want to compare this given hash with the file to see if it is in the file.
I chose BinarySearch for this. My current problem is to find the correct index for the rightmost element.

```
def binarySearch (l, r, x):

# Check base case
if r >= l:

mid = l + (r - l)/2

# If element is present at the middle itself
if getLineFromFile(mid) == x:
    return mid

# If element is smaller than mid, then it
# can only be present in left subarray
elif getLineFromFile(mid) > x:
    return binarySearch(l, mid-1, x)

# Else the element can only be present
# in right subarray
else:
    return binarySearch(mid + 1, r, x)

else:
   # Element is not present in the array
   return -1

x = '0000000A0E3B9F25FF41DE4B5AC238C2D545C7A8:15'

def getLineFromFile(lineNumber):
 with open('testfile.txt') as f:
  for i, line in enumerate(f):
   if i == lineNumber:
    return line
else:
 print('Not 7 lines in file')
 line = None

# get last Element of List
def tail():
 for line in open('pwned.txt', 'r'):
   pass
else:
  print line

ausgabetail = tail()
#print ausgabetail
result = binarySearch( 0, ausgabetail, x)
if result != -1:
  print "Element is present at index % d" % result
else:
   print "Element is not present in array"
```

My problem now is to get the correct index for the right side for the binary search. I pass the function (l, r, x). The left side starts at the beginning with 0. The right side should be the end of the file so the last line. I try to get that but it doesn't work. I tried to get this with the Funktion tail(). But if I print r on testing, I get the value "None". Do you have another idea here?

Comment: I don't quite get your idea of the algorithm. 1. Are your hashes sorted in that file? (required for binary search) 2. You can't access an arbitrary line of a text file, which makes it imo not possible to implement binary search correctly. You already addressed this fact by creating `getLineFromFile()` - but this _searches_  for the correct line _over and over again_. So it will from my point of view be more efficient to simply loop over the file and check in every line if the hash is found...

Comment: @SpghttCd Yes the file is ordered by hash. It's also a massive txt file (11GB). I think simply loop over the file would take a long time? Could you give me an example of your idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example as requested in comments above

```
def checkForHash(h, fname):
    with open(fname) as f:
        for i, line in enumerate(f):
            if h == line:
                return i
    return -1

x = '0000000A0E3B9F25FF41DE4B5AC238C2D545C7A8:15'
checkForHash (x, 'testfile.txt')
```

Comment: thanks for your example. How do I get it right that the string will compare as a whole and not parts of it?
Example
x= 12345
Then it also returns results if the substring 12345 appears somewhere. Also the Performance is not the greatest but I don't know any other way.

Comment: Edited to `if h == line:` so it asks for equality.

Comment: Well, of course performance is not too great when you search for sth in an 11GB file... The problem is IO here: if you don't have the data already in memory you cannot access an arbitrary element n in that list, but this is what binary search needs besides a sorted list. In the algorithm you will soon want to access the last element (see your own title) - and this is the point where your `getLineFromFile(lineNumber)` function will need  the same time only for returning the line for the algorithm like the simple iterate-through-file-until-found approach above needs for the whole search.

Comment: Thanks for your great response :). I'm really happy with that. Now i have one last question: My text file looks like this:
6E252D5ED04B0A3D34CC5EEE0DB42FB1C7C0FEBA:1
5BAA61E4C9B93F3F0682250B6CF8331B7EE68FD8:3730471

Now I just want everything before the colon(:). I know that with if h == line[:-4]: the last 4 characters are cut away but the number behind the colon is variable. Therefore I need something universal. Do you have an idea here?

Comment: You could use `if h == line.split(':')[0]:` if that's the only colon here; otherwise have a look at `str.rsplit()`: `if h == line.rsplit(':', 1)[0]:`

Comment: BTW in your case it would be perhaps interesting if rsplit is generally faster because you know the colon always is at the end of the string. You could test that with your 11GB bunch of hashes... PS: I checked a few Timings and rsplit itself is not faster; but the use of the 1 (which is the maxsplit kwarg) seems to make it slightly faster sometimes, so perhaps you simply try it.

Comment: Thanks again for your response. I've tried it and it doesn't make any difference. Both take about 75 seconds. I have to see if I can manipulate my input file in such a way that everything behind the colon is gone before i start to compare. So it almost halves the time

Comment: The part left of the colon is also not the same length in every line?

Comment: the left side always has the exact same length. It is only the right side that changes.

Comment: Then why not `if h == line[:40]:`?

Comment: PS: rsplit with maxsplit=1 is definitely faster than split - but not at such short strings. And not searching at all but simple indexing is even faster. However, IMO 99% of your time consumption is IO in your case.

Comment: Great idea and the performance is the same as when I cut away behind signs with [:-X]. You helped me a lot. Thank you very much! I marked your answer as a solution :).